# Variables changing when using certain methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

So lets say I have a variable called array:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
```

when I use the `reverse()` method it reverses the array, as expected

```
array.reverse()
```

but lets say I want to keep the original variable so I make a "temporary" variable

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayRev = array.reverse()
console.log(arrayRev)
console.log(array)
```

but array is also reversed.
how do I know when the original variable changes and when it doesn't?

Thanks if you can help

Comment: You need to know about the methods, whether they do the changes in-place or not. reverse does the changes in-place so it changes the original variables value.

Comment: `arrayRev = array.slice().reverse()`

Comment: when you use an an api function, it's best to refer to its documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse
States that the function is destructive and it changes the original array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayRev =[...array].reverse()
console.log(arrayRev)
console.log(array)
```